# Repeat or reference a figure in another rst file

Tags: python-sphinx, restructuredtext

I have two files named `a.rst` and `b.rst`, both of which contain a good deal of text. In `a.rst`, I define a figure:

```
.. figure:: ../images/some-image.png
    :scale: 70%
    :align: center
    :alt: Some Text
    
    Some Caption
```

I would like to have the same image and caption in `b.rst` with the same figure number, But repeating the above code gives me a new figure.

As a compromise, I can refer to this image in `b.rst` using the `:numref:` directive, but that does not resolve to the figure. It only displays the name as a piece of code.

I understand that these are two question, but I think they are sufficiently related. How can I repeat or reference a figure defined in a rst file in another file.

**Edit** to elaborate on the expected output:
I want the resulting files to have the following content:

- `a.html`:

```
Fig. 1 + caption
Fig. 2 + caption
Fig. 3 + caption
```

- `b.html`:

```
Fig. 4 + caption
Fig. 2 + caption
Fig. 5 + caption
```

Effectively, this would add the figure to `b.rst` not as a separate entity, but merely as a mirror of what was in `a.rst`. This is similar to what was discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/200211/).

Comment: Hello @MohammadrezaKhoshbin, if the answer solved your problem you should accept it by clicking the green check mark on the left side of the answer. (It helps users who are searching to know the question has a solution, and it rewards the person who answered.)

Comment: @bad_coder Sadly it didn't. While the answer was very useful, I believe the problem cannot be solved at this point in time.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming you want to repeat the exact same content in two different files, put that content into a separate file, then [include](https://docutils.sourceforge.io/docs/ref/rst/directives.html#include) that file wherever you want it to appear.

### includeme.rst

Note document root relative path.

```
.. figure:: /images/some-image.png
    :scale: 70%
    :align: center
    :alt: Some Text
    
    Some Caption
```

### a.rst and b.rst

```
Below this paragraph should appear an image.

..include:: /includeme.rst
```

**EDIT**

To remove the figure number, set [`numfig` to `False`](https://www.sphinx-doc.org/en/master/usage/configuration.html#confval-numfig).  This will avoid the incongruent figure numbering, but won't solve it.  I think that's the best you can achieve, as Sphinx automatically numbers figures (and other objects) otherwise.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. While this generates the figure, it my tests the figures were identical but completely separate. Particularly, they had different figure numbers. This solution is useful for complicated figures, but it does not satisfy my requirements.

Comment: Are you saying that the images are copies of one another, but in different locations? I don't understand "separate"—from what? To what figure numbers and complicated figures do you refer? This solution might still be useful for your use case.

Comment: I edited the question to elaborate on the expected output. The answer is very useful for having a single source for the figure but, every time its included a new figure is created and these figures don't have the same figure numbers.

Comment: I've added a reference to `numfig` in my answer.